# Regex to strip non utf-8 characters but new line

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I have a string which contains a new line feed and some non-utf8 characters. I'm trying to write some regex that will replace non utf-8 characters but it should keep the line endings.

Below is what I have from PHP

```
PHP preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

It's stripping the non utf-8 characters but it's also stripping the new line endings and I can't find out how to do this.

I've tried `/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF\^\n]/` but hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead at the start. Now this won't match newline character.

```
preg_replace('/(?!\n)[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

or

```
preg_replace('/(?![\n\r])[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```